# Asynchronous calls with transactions

Tags: c#, sql, wcf, transactions

I am writing a WCF application with asynchronous calls. Such calls are executing a stored procedures (which are transaction [isolated]).

What happens when stored procedure from one user runs and meanwhile another several calls arrive, with stored procedures, affecting the same database tables?

Should I implement a queue or does WCF support it?

Comment: What do you *want* to happen in such situations?  You can likely use transactions within the SP to get the needed behavior.

Comment: @Servy - this is what i do transaction + SP.I am just afraid that the calls which arrived during this transaction execution will not execute ever.Who cares that the will be executed / in each order?Is there any queue in wcf for that?or I as a programmer should implement such queue?

Comment: If you're making the calls they won't be skipped entirely.  It would be a *major* bug somewhere if it did.  If you are using transactions then you can be sure they will all run, and there will be *some* logical ordering of transactions (although you don't know what that order will be in advance).  That's the *point* of transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the entire point of using Database transactions. They ensure operations on any database is atomic.

Even if you weren't doing async calls in .Net, if you have 2 applications access the same database at the same time, you would want the queries from each application to be done within the context of a database transaction so they happen isolated and independently from another.

TransactionScope in .NET is great for this

```
using(TransactionScope tran = new TransactionScope()) {
    CallAMethodThatDoesDBWork();

    tran.Complete();
}
```

If your code errors, Dispose() will be called without Complete(), so it will be rolled back.